# Set systemd timer to an odd and specific number of days

Tags: centos, systemd, systemd-timer, letsencrypt, certbot

I'm using systemd.timers on CentOS 7 server and have a timer set to automatically renew Certbot-managed Let's Encrypt website certificate.

autorenewal.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=certbot certificate auto-renewal service file

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/certbot-auto renew

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

autorenewal.timer:

```
[Unit]
Description=Renew certs every 10th every 3 months

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-2,5,8,11-10 08:00:00
Persistent=true
Unit=certbotautorenewal.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The problem is that, as far as I know, with OnCalendar events the timer can be set only to specific date (say, every 15-th of every month or every 3 months), but Let's Encrypt certificate expires after a specific number of days (90). I want to renew the certificate a bit earlier, say, every 83 days or even two months and a half. I know Let's Encrypt expiry bot recommends renewing every 60 days, but I don't really trust it, since the expiration notice messages start coming when the certificate expires in 20 days, not 30. I don't want to renew the certificate when it's not due yet, because the renew command will be ignored and when it is finally needed a month after, it won't be there.
Right now I use a clumsy workaround where I have to set the "every 3 months on a particular day" renewal time several days earlier after every renewal.
Is there an actual solution to this? Because for some reason, certbot forces systemd timers usage on CentOS 7 instead of cron. Maybe there is hidden a subtract option in timer syntax? Or, for example, using bash to sync the calendar with the number of days.

Comment: "because the renew command will be ignored" -- are you sure it will be ignored? or is that just certbot? I have some LE certificates that get renewed once a month, and they work fine. That's with acme-tiny.

Comment: Though of course if certbot sends the actual renewal request only if the certificate is nearing expiration, then there's not much harm in running the renewal program too often.